# JavaScript function variable scope

Tags: javascript, function, scope

In the following code, why can I access the variable x.b? Shouldn't it have a local scope?

**CODE**

```
function x() {
    var a = 3;
}


x.b = 8;

console.log(x.a);
console.log(x.b);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
undefined
8
```

Comment: I think because the function is an object you can access, and you just gave it a new property "b"

Comment: Both `x` and `x.b` were defined in global scope. So why do you expect them to have "local scope"?

Comment: There appears to be some fundamental misunderstanding. Dot notation does not access local variables.

Comment: You might want to be aware that you are adding a property to a function, which is probably not what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `var` to declare `a` within `x`'s constructor, `a` is mark as  private, however when you do `x.b` you are essentially saying - add the property `b` to the object `x`.

Hence when you do `x.b`, technically speaking you are accessing object `x`'s property `b`, which is 8.

Comment: But `x` is not a constructor here, nor is it being used as one; it's just a plain old function.

Comment: @torazaburo correct. `x` is just a plain old function. I thought I saw the `new` keyword somewhere the last time... Hmm I must be tired :(

Answer (score 0):

You have defined x.b to 8 and it becomes a global var. Which means you can access it from anywhere.

So the x() is a function which has its own scope. So you can't access the vars inside a function scope in the mentioned way. However you can access the 'a' by doing this and calling the x function.

```
function x() {
  var a = 3;
  return a;
}
```

Comment: `x.b` is **not** a "global var". It's a property on an object called `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript considers x.b as a global object. so you can access it even inside the function like:

```
x.b = 8;
function x() {
    var a = 3;
    alert(x.b)
}
x();
console.log(x.a);
console.log(x.b);
```

But make sure you specify x.b before function declaration.

whereas object a is specified inside the function x() which makes it private thats why you are getting undefined result for console.log(x.a);

if you write it like this:

```
a = 5;
function x() {
    var a = 3;
}
x.b = 8;

alert(a);
alert(x.b);
```

you will get results as bellow:

```
5
8
```

for javascript a and x.a are two separate objects.